# Android ACTION_PICK for SD folder on emulator

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I am looking to pick from the images stored on my emulator SD card. For this project I am only concerned with the emulator, I don't have to make allowances for real world mobile devices.

I have copied images to my emulator SD card, but I do not see those images when I run the following code:

```
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Barcodes");
    Log.i(TAG, "folder is " + folder);
    Uri folderURI = Uri.fromFile(folder);
    imgPicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, folderURI);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

Any Pointers? When I run the activity I do not see the photos that I've copied to my emulator file system.

[image]

Comment: It makes no sense to use a folder uri as action pick will neglect it. Probably the mediastore has not seen those files yet. Reboot the emulator.

Comment: Thank you @blackapps your comment pointed me in the right direction. A restart wasn't enough, as it turns out I needed to update my platform tools SDK.   I appreciate the advice on the folder uri as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to Platform Tools SDK fixed this issue